# When changing Raised Button to Elevated Button, creates an error on the button style

Tags: flutter, dart, calculator

```
class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  Widget calcbutton(String btntxt, Color btncolor, Color txtcolor) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          calculation(btntxt);
        },
        child: Text(
          btntxt,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 35,
            color: txtcolor,
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        Color: btncolor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When changing the Raised Button to ElevatedButton, errors on shape, Color, padding immediately appear

Answer (score 1):

With the new `ElevatedButton`, these settings are now in the `style` property.
In your case, this example should do it.
You can set other properties inside `Elevatedbutton.styleFrom`

```dart
return ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text(
    btntxt,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 35,
      color: txtcolor,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have elevated button with the `shape`, `color`, and `padding` options available, use [`MaterialButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html). You can set elevation for various state of the button.

```dart
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {
    calculation(btntxt);
  },
  child: Text(
    btntxt,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 35,
      color: txtcolor,
    ),
  ), 
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  color: btncolor,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  // set elevation options below
  elevation: 2,
  focusElevation: 4,
  hoverElevation: 4,
  highlightElevation: 8,
  disabledElevation: 0,
),
```